# Import Hudson jobs to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I'm trying to import Hudson(v3.1.2) jobs into Jenkins, but it seems that the config files differ in structure. Information about Git repository and MSBuild settings will not be read by Jenkins.

Anyone know if there's a way to get around this?

Comment: Have you checked that the same plugins are installed and running in both the Hudson and Jenkins instance?

Comment: Yes, same plugins installed.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/arKSTc3Fz3Q), config files can be updated to new format with a style sheet transformation, as described in this [message](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/arKSTc3Fz3Q/m/2JsQk9E0_eAJ):

(nb the attachment is available in google groups)

> The attachment contains my (very unpolished) code to convert the hudson 2.2 config format to that of jenkins.
>
> Please note that it is not complete, only parts that we use are covered. But it should be easy from the examples to extend it.
>
> Furthermore, after the migration, I discovered an error I made: the cvs scm info that I retained is incorrect. You should use the stuff that is found under /maven2-moduleset/project-properties/entry[string/text()='scm'].
>
> Finally, add xalan-2.7.1.jar and serializer-2.7.1.jar to the project. They are needed to enable the use of exslt

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to upgrade your existing Hudson instance to Jenkins (to migrate the job configuration).

And next, you can try to import the migrated jobs into your new Jenkins server.

Please do a backup before upgrading your Hudson instance :)

Comment: How do I upgrade Hudson instance to Jenkins?

Comment: Upgrade = update the war file from Hudson 3.1.2 to the target Jenkins version (in a staging area if you can). Then I hope Jenkins will migrate your config.xml files when you will restart the Jenkins service.

Comment: Unfortunately same result. Everything is loaded but build steps and git information is missing.

Comment: Another solution should be to do incremental upgrades = instead of upgrading from Hudson 3.1.2 to the latest Jenkins version, apply several upgrades (Hudson 3.1.2 to the latest Hudson version, latest Hudson to Jenkins 1.5.x, Jenkins 1.5.x to the latest Jenkins version). It's just an idea.

Comment: This didn't work either, I've been struggling with this for a while now and I guess that the fastest way around this is manual go through all projects and copy and paste information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, according to the official [migration guide](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Upgrading+from+Hudson+to+Jenkins), the automatic upgrade works only from Hudson <= 1.395, so migrating from Hudson 3.1.2 shouldn't definitely work at all...

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available to import jobs 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin

It mentions -

> You may also be able to import jobs from a Hudson instance as well,
>   but compatibility is not a primary goal of this plugin.